# Foreign key constraint fails even if parent row is present

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following 2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `RuleEntity` (
`rule_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`action_word` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`condition_word` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`ruleGUID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`rule_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`caseflag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`globalflag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`multilineflag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`isDefault` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`rule_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `ruleGUID` (`ruleGUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `PreProcessorRule` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`rank` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`rule_rule_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`defaultRuleGUID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FK4BD420EB4273A655` (`rule_rule_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK4BD420EB4273A655` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_rule_id`) REFERENCES `RuleEntity` (`rule_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I am trying to insert 1 row in RuleEntiy and another in PreprocessorRule. But it fails with foreign key constraint.

```
INSERT INTO `RuleEntity` (`rule_id`,`action_word`,`condition_word`,`description`,`caseflag`,`globalflag`,`multilineflag`,`name`,`ruleGUID`,`rule_type`, `isDefault`) VALUES ( '1',' ','[^\\x00-\\x7F]','HF Default Rule:  Removes Non-ASCII Character.',1,1,1,'HF: Non-ASCII Remover','1157B568665E08','CUSTOM', 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

INSERT INTO `HFP`.`PreProcessorRule` (`id`, `rank`, `rule_rule_id`) VALUES ('1', '0', '1');
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`HFP`.`PreProcessorRule`, CONSTRAINT `FK4BD420EB4273A655` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_rule_id`) REFERENCES `RuleEntity` (`rule_id`))
```

I ran same sql on local MySQL 5.1 on MAC OS X 10.9. It worked. Now I am trying to run it on the Amazon RDS MySQL where I get this error.

Kindly let me know what is going wrong?

Comment: Try to define the foreign key as NOT NULL

Comment: Not sure whether it matters, but why are you passing your integer values in as strings?

Comment: even if I pass it as integer it fails with same error. These sql ran on my Mac OS X Mysql 5.1 but failing on Ubuntu 5.1

Comment: I've run these queries and receive no foreign key constraint errors, but I removed the schema name from the second one (obviously) to get it to work.  Otherwise I changed nothing.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: Correct. It works on all, but unfortunately it is failing on my ubuntu server.

Comment: Yup, works fine on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3f375/1/0). @subhashlg26 suggest you add that information to the question since it massively changes the problem.

Comment: How did you create the table on the new server? Using those create statements above, or did you migrate the entire table from your mac?

Comment: Those tables are created by Hibernate. I create another database on same instance and executed same script. And it is working fine.

Comment: You only set the schema (`HFP`) in the last query. Do you have more than on `PreProcessorRule` table?

Comment: Hit SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; and try to insert and check table data, and let us know.

Comment: @RaviParekh it worked. But can you point me to its side effects?

Comment: It won't check any foreign key constraint. Have you checked the table data? is it duplicate?

Comment: I am not putting duplicate data. It has worked. It is good for me that SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; works for session.